# the classes are not accessible under the same name space C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, namespaces

The project is in C# ASP.NET; I have some classes under the same namespace. I put them in a separate folder of the project. The problem is that these classes are not accessible to others in this folder.

```
namespace MNS
{
    public class data_api
    {
        public string key { get; set; }

        public decimal? value { get; set; }
        public string datetime { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MNS
{
    public class respuestaJson
    {
        public byte estatus { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public List<List<data_api>> json_respuesta { get; set; }
    }
}
```

these two classes are separate files in the same folder, but I have an error in the "respuestaJson" class that is shown: " CS0246 The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

when I create the same file in the App_Code folder, it is working

Comment: Then they are under different namespace

Comment: all namespaces are the same

Comment: Can't be. Check spelling, casing etc. There might be a miss

Comment: @Rahul I checked many times, the strange part is that all are same just this folder has the problem

Comment: at the start of the file add using MNS;
maybe it will help...

Comment: Have you include the `System.Collections.Generic` for the `List<T>`?

Comment: @HentaiLord that is not working because they are the same namespace

Comment: @MartinBackasch yes

Comment: the error is in this line public List<List<data_api>> json_respuesta { get; set; } or in the using on the top??

Comment: @dimath when I want to create an Object from data_api class, I have the problem

Comment: @Sasan.R maybe u can try restarting the visual studio once.

Comment: @akg179 that is not working

Comment: Have you included the data_api.cs file in your VS project? (Right-click the file, include in project)

Comment: @Phil yes it is included

Comment: @Sasan.R the only thing I can suggest is an issue somewhere in your csproj file, try excluding the parent directories of the respuestaJson and data_api files and including them again. Then rebuild your project.